# IzPack xml <args> problems, cannot pass $INSTALL_PATH to exectuable script

Tags: xml, ant, installation, izpack

I have an install file in xml that I am having trouble with. I cannot get the $INSTALL_PATH to be passed as an arg to an exectuable script that I wrote after installation finishes. Here is my code:

(In my install.xml)

```
<executable stage="postInstall" targetfile="./testScript.sh" keep="true">
    <args>
        <arg value=$INSTALL_PATH/>
    </args>
</executable>
```

(My testScript.sh)

```
echo $1 >> configFile.txt
```

I just get blank file in configFile.txt, I expect to see my install path for my program.

Comment: I add this to my script, echo $0 >> configFile.txt and it outputs the script name as expected, but why can I not get anything from my <arg> tag? It makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that my code above does work, the problem was that I got stuck with a stale installer jar at one point and while I was recompiling it, I wasn't using the new one! The code above works. It really is not that complicated :)